# Kivy Android Crush | Urlrequest

Tags: python, android, kivy, web-crawler

I am a new bee in kivy and this is the first time I tried to write an Android app since think it is cool that writing an Android app in python.

I am writing a crawler and tried to pack it to an apk.
Everything works fine on my Laptop. (Deepin 15.11)

But finally, when I packed it into apk and run it on my cell phone, it crashed after it showed the result I needed.

So, here the problem is I got what I want from the Internet. But it crashed after a few seconds.

I checked the log and try to find someone who had the same problem. And some of them say it is because the request is keeping alive when it supposed to be disconnected.

my `Urlrequests` function shows like that:

```
    def search_location(self):
        search_template = "http://*****"
        headers = {#"Accept" : "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
            "Accept-Encoding" : "gzip,deflate,sdch",
            "Accept-Language" : "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en;q=0.6",
            "Connection" : "keep-alive",
            "Cookie" : "ASP.NET_SessionI*****",
            "Host" : "****",
            "Referer" : "http://***",
            "User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36",
            "X-Requested-With" : "XMLHttpRequest"
            }
        # search_template = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q={}&typle=like&appid=xyz"    # Replace 'xyz' with your API Key (APPID)
        search_url = search_template.format(self.search_input.text)
        request = UrlRequest(search_url, self.found_location, req_headers = headers)

    def found_location(self, request, data):
        print("\n"*3,type(data),"\n"*3)
        data = eval(data) if not isinstance(data, dict) else data
        Result = ["{} ({})".format( d['file_name'].replace("HRB-1_","").replace(".zip","") +"   "+
                                    d['file_state'].replace("已处理","Done")+"   "+
                                    d['file_upload_time'].split(" ")[-1]+"   "+
                                    d['file_download_time'].split(" ")[-1],
                                    d['file_state'].replace("已处理","Done")) for d in data['griddata']]
        self.search_results.data = [{'text': str(x)} for x in Result]
```

And the Andoird log shows:

This is what I get by `adb catalog| grep kivy`

```
10-25 20:02:45.573  1301  3041 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 hwFlg=0x10 cmp=org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity bnds=[40,116][292,431]} from uid 10079
10-25 20:02:45.574  1301  3041 I ActivityTaskManager: ActivityRecord info: ActivityInfo{6dfc8fb org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:45.579  1301  3041 D ActivityTaskManager: TaskLaunchParamsModifier:task=null activity=ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t-1} display-from-source=0 display-id=0 display-windowing-mode=1
10-25 20:02:45.579  1301  3041 D ActivityTaskManager: TaskLaunchParamsModifier:task=null activity=ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t-1} display-from-source=0 display-id=0 display-windowing-mode=1 activity-options-fullscreen=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) inherit-fullscreen non-freeform-display
10-25 20:02:45.582  1301  3041 D ActivityTaskManager: TaskLaunchParamsModifier:task=TaskRecord{6dd5b31 #97 A=org.test.ruibio U=0 StackId=96 sz=0} activity=ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t-1} display-from-task=0 display-id=0 display-windowing-mode=1 activity-options-fullscreen=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) inherit-fullscreen non-freeform-display
10-25 20:02:45.584  1301  3041 V ActivityTaskManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{712cf67 token=Token{6fddb12 ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t97}}} task={taskId=97 appTokens=[] mdr=false} at 2147483647
10-25 20:02:45.588  1301  1474 I HwAudioServiceEx: ComponentInfo : className = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity, flag=showStartingWindow, isHomeActivity=, isTop=false
10-25 20:02:45.612  1301  1485 I ActivityManager: Start proc 28105:org.test.ruibio/u0a373 for activity {org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:45.615  1301  1462 I WindowManager: Check opening app=AppWindowToken{712cf67 token=Token{6fddb12 ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t97}}}: allDrawn=false startingDisplayed=true startingMoved=false isRelaunching()=false startingWindow=Window{6f8cce1 u0 Splash Screen org.test.ruibio}
10-25 20:02:45.615   920  1101 I Screem  : <LOGMGR> <CreateNewActivityStartTask> [FLOW ERR, app=com.huawei.android.launcher/ is starting, run new app=org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity time=21161152]
10-25 20:02:45.616  1301  1462 D RemoteAnimationController: createAnimationAdapter(): token=AppWindowToken{712cf67 token=Token{6fddb12 ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t97}}}
10-25 20:02:45.747 28105 28105 D ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{3c3b845 token=android.os.BinderProxy@fd6f451 {org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@fd6f451
10-25 20:02:45.756  1301  3081 I WindowManager: addWindow: Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:45.759  5202  5248 I AppLifeChangeSensor: CAWARENESS: activityResumed componentName = ComponentInfo{org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:45.760  1301  1474 I HwAudioServiceEx: ComponentInfo : className = org.kivy.android.PythonActivity, flag=onResume, isHomeActivity=, isTop=true
10-25 20:02:45.760  2225  2525 D DollieActivityManagerAdapter: [Resumed] bg:true pid:28105 uid:10373 ComponentInfo{org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:45.760  2225  2525 E DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity state:2 fg:true mUid:10373
10-25 20:02:45.798  1301  1899 I WindowManager: Changing focus from null to Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:4543092 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked:4545052 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.relayoutWindow:4700852 com.android.server.wm.Session.relayout:4694660 
10-25 20:02:45.798  1301  1899 V HwPhoneWindowManager: updateSystemUiColorLw window=Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity},EmuiStyle=0,StatusBarColor=0xff000000,NavigationBarColor=0xfffcfcfc, mForceNotchStatusBar=false
10-25 20:02:45.799  1301  1459 I StatusBarDisable: setFlags what=0 which=1 pkg=Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:45.838 28105 28153 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
10-25 20:02:45.842  1301  1462 I WindowManager: dispatchResized : win = Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} drawState = READY_TO_SHOW
10-25 20:02:45.844  1301  1479 I ActivityTaskManager: Displayed org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity: +271ms
10-25 20:02:45.845  1301  1459 I StatusBarDisable: setFlags what=0 which=1 pkg=Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:45.866  1301  3595 V ActivityTaskManager: Activity idle: Token{6fddb12 ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t97}}
10-25 20:02:45.909 28105 28153 I python  : [INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /data/user/0/org.test.ruibio/files/app/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-10-25_1.txt
10-25 20:02:45.909 28105 28153 I python  : [INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/data/user/0/org.test.ruibio/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/kivy/__init__.pyc"
10-25 20:02:45.962  1301  1462 I WindowManager: Removing Window{6f8cce1 u0 Splash Screen org.test.ruibio} from AppWindowToken{712cf67 token=Token{6fddb12 ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t97}}}
10-25 20:02:46.487  1301  3081 I DebugKeepScreenOn: Acquiring screen wakelock due to Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:46.674  1301  1459 I StatusBarDisable: setFlags what=0 which=1 pkg=Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:46.675  1301  3081 I WindowManager: dispatchResized : win = Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} drawState = HAS_DRAWN
10-25 20:02:53.507  1301  1459 I StatusBarDisable: setFlags what=0 which=1 pkg=Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:53.508  1301  3595 I WindowManager: dispatchResized : win = Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} drawState = HAS_DRAWN
10-25 20:02:53.831 28105 28153 I python  :    File "/home/ken/test/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Ruibio/kivy/app.py", line 855, in run
10-25 20:02:53.832 28105 28153 I python  :    File "/home/ken/test/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Ruibio/kivy/base.py", line 504, in runTouchApp
10-25 20:02:53.833 28105 28153 I python  :    File "/home/ken/test/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Ruibio/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 747, in mainloop
10-25 20:02:53.835 28105 28153 I python  :    File "/home/ken/test/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Ruibio/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 479, in _mainloop
10-25 20:02:53.836 28105 28153 I python  :    File "/home/ken/test/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Ruibio/kivy/base.py", line 339, in idle
10-25 20:02:53.836 28105 28153 I python  :    File "/home/ken/test/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Ruibio/kivy/clock.py", line 591, in tick
10-25 20:02:53.838 28105 28153 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 384, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
10-25 20:02:53.838 28105 28153 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 414, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
10-25 20:02:53.840 28105 28153 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 412, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
10-25 20:02:53.841 28105 28153 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 154, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
10-25 20:02:53.842 28105 28153 I python  :    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 86, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.get_callback
10-25 20:02:53.843 28105 28153 I python  :    File "/home/ken/test/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Ruibio/kivy/weakmethod.py", line 56, in is_dead
10-25 20:02:54.337  1301 28225 W ActivityTaskManager:   finishTopCrashedActivityLocked Force finishing activity org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
10-25 20:02:54.338  1301 28225 W HwActivityTaskManagerServiceEx: setResumedActivityUncheckLocked start call, from: ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t97 f}, to: ActivityRecord{70f1783 u0 com.huawei.android.launcher/.unihome.UniHomeLauncher t1}
10-25 20:02:54.340  1301 28225 I WindowManager: Changing focus from Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} to null displayId=0 Callers=com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.updateFocusedWindowLocked:4543092 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateFocusedWindowLocked:4545052 com.android.server.wm.ActivityDisplay.setFocusedApp:1243036 com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.setResumedActivityUncheckLocked:1353360 
10-25 20:02:54.409  1301  1799 W InputDispatcher: channel '73c02e1 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
10-25 20:02:54.410  1301  1799 E InputDispatcher: channel '73c02e1 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-25 20:02:54.410  1301  1799 I WindowManager: WINDOW DIED Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:54.410  1301  1799 I WindowManager: removeIfPossible: Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeIfPossible:1371760 com.android.server.wm.InputManagerCallback.notifyInputChannelBroken:15045748 com.android.server.input.InputManagerService.notifyInputChannelBroken:17082312 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> 
10-25 20:02:54.410  1301  1799 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '73c02e1 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)'
10-25 20:02:54.411  1301  1799 I WindowManager: Not removing Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity EXITING} due to exit animation 
10-25 20:02:54.418  1301  2018 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity EXITING}
10-25 20:02:54.419  1301  3100 E InputDispatcher: Window handle Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} has no registered input channel
10-25 20:02:54.419  1301  2018 I WindowManager: removeIfPossible: Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity EXITING} callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:7015256 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:3939612 <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> <bottom of call stack> 
10-25 20:02:54.419  1301  2018 I WindowManager: Not removing Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity EXITING} due to exit animation 
10-25 20:02:54.425  1301  3099 I WindowManager: Exit animation finished in Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity EXITING}: remove=true
10-25 20:02:54.425  1301  3099 E WindowManager: win=Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity EXITING} destroySurfaces: appStopped=false win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=true win.mRemoveOnExit=true
10-25 20:02:54.426  1301  3099 I WindowManager: postWindowRemoveCleanupLocked: Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
10-25 20:02:54.426  1301  3099 I WindowManager: Removing Window{73c02e1 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity} from AppWindowToken{712cf67 token=Token{6fddb12 ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t97}}}
10-25 20:02:54.428  1301  3099 V WindowManager: removeAppToken: AppWindowToken{712cf67 token=Token{6fddb12 ActivityRecord{7408a87 u0 org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t97}}} delayed=true Callers=com.android.server.wm.DisplayContent.removeAppToken:7292936 com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.removeWindowContainer:7295732 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.removeActivityFromHistoryLocked:7294852 com.android.server.wm.ActivityStack.removeHistoryRecordsForAppLocked:4622128 
10-25 20:02:54.442  2225  2525 E DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity state:20 fg:false mUid:10373
```

This is what I get by `adb catalog *:E`

```
10-25 20:14:46.098 31968 32021 E libc++abi: terminating
10-25 20:14:46.098 31968 32021 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 32021 (SDLThread), pid 31968 (org.test.ruibio)
10-25 20:14:46.172 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-25 20:14:46.172 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/VOG-AL10/HWVOG:10/HUAWEIVOG-AL10/10.1.0.162C00:user/release-keys'
10-25 20:14:46.172 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
10-25 20:14:46.172 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
10-25 20:14:46.172 32080 32080 E libc    : Access denied finding property "persist.mygote.disable"
10-25 20:14:46.172 32080 32080 E libc    : Access denied finding property "persist.mygote.escape.enable"
10-25 20:14:46.177 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : SYSVMTYPE: Maple
10-25 20:14:46.177 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : APPVMTYPE: Art
10-25 20:14:46.177 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2020-10-25 20:14:46+0800
10-25 20:14:46.177 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : pid: 31968, tid: 32021, name: SDLThread  >>> org.test.ruibio <<<
10-25 20:14:46.177 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : uid: 10373
10-25 20:14:46.177 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
10-25 20:14:46.177 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'terminating'
10-25 20:14:46.177 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :     r0  00000000  r1  00007d15  r2  00000006  r3  c272a8d0
10-25 20:14:46.178 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :     r4  c272a8e4  r5  c272a8c8  r6  00007ce0  r7  0000016b
10-25 20:14:46.178 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :     r8  c272a8e0  r9  c272a8d0  r10 c272a900  r11 c272a8f0
10-25 20:14:46.178 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :     ip  00007d15  sp  c272a8a0  lr  f20a0143  pc  f20a0156
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : 
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 00054156  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166) (BuildId: 2ae2ed355dc68e7fe1e09d70518111d1)
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 0003606d  /system/lib/libc++.so (abort_message+88) (BuildId: fa0397c630f1e14558b6409ed72175a4)
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 0003615d  /system/lib/libc++.so (demangling_terminate_handler()+20) (BuildId: fa0397c630f1e14558b6409ed72175a4)
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00044eef  /system/lib/libc++.so (std::__terminate(void (*)())+2) (BuildId: fa0397c630f1e14558b6409ed72175a4)
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00044ea1  /system/lib/libc++.so (std::terminate()+40) (BuildId: fa0397c630f1e14558b6409ed72175a4)
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00080527  /system/lib/libc++.so (std::__1::thread::~thread()+10) (BuildId: fa0397c630f1e14558b6409ed72175a4)
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 0009e4ff  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__cxa_finalize+142) (BuildId: 2ae2ed355dc68e7fe1e09d70518111d1)
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 000997d3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (exit+10) (BuildId: 2ae2ed355dc68e7fe1e09d70518111d1)
10-25 20:14:46.183 32080 32080 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 0018f384  /data/app/org.test.ruibio-dml7jFE0sURF1XEvsG452w==/lib/arm/libpython3.8m.so (Py_Exit+28)
10-25 20:14:46.529   921   921 E /system/bin/tombstoned: Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_08
10-25 20:14:46.531  1301 32084 E HwActivityTaskManagerServiceEx: invalid ActivityRecord, error.
10-25 20:14:46.531  1301 32084 E HwActivityTaskManagerServiceEx: parse activity info error.
10-25 20:14:46.537   920  3771 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
10-25 20:14:46.539   920  3770 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
10-25 20:14:46.539   920  3770 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
10-25 20:14:46.539   920  3771 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
10-25 20:14:46.539   920  3771 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
10-25 20:14:46.539   920  3770 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
10-25 20:14:46.539   920  3770 E         : FaultDetect: DumptoolPrintf return.
10-25 20:14:46.539   920  3770 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
10-25 20:14:46.552  2267  4010 E AwareLog: SPKEQSchedFeature: Uid has been sent, ignore.
10-25 20:14:46.552  2267  4010 E AwareLog: SPKVolumeSchedFeature: Uid has been sent, ignore.
10-25 20:14:46.558   920  3771 E         : FaultDetect: FaultEngineTracePrintf return.
10-25 20:14:46.559  2225  2812 E Hicom_MpFlowDecisionSystem: getMultipathFlowByPkgName. multipathPolicy is illegal
10-25 20:14:46.559  2225  2812 E Hicom_MpFlowDecisionSystem: startMpFlow. multipathFlow is illegal
10-25 20:14:46.571  2225  2525 E DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:org.test.ruibio/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity state:20 fg:false mUid:10373
10-25 20:14:46.572  2225  2525 E HwPacketFilterBypass: sendRequestToKernel DEL_UID [10373]
10-25 20:14:46.573  2267  4081 E AwareLog: Stub: processProcessDied has not been overridden!
10-25 20:14:46.573  5202  5248 E AppLifeChangeSensor: CAWARENESS: activityResumed mAppLifeChangeCallback is null 
10-25 20:14:46.573  2225  7959 E HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 102
10-25 20:14:46.575  2225  2812 E Hicom_PolicyCenterService: remove bind rules with uid = 10373have no policy
10-25 20:14:46.575  2225  2812 E Hicom_PolicyCenterService: handleAppDied. multipathPolicy
10-25 20:14:46.576  2225  2525 E SmartDualCardConfig: isAppInBlackList false,items==null
10-25 20:14:46.576  2225  2525 E DollieAdapterService: notifyActivityState pkg:com.huawei.android.launcher/com.huawei.android.launcher.unihome.UniHomeLauncher state:2 fg:true mUid:10079
10-25 20:14:46.578  2225  2525 E SmartDualCardConfig: isAppInBlackList false,items==null
10-25 20:14:46.591  1301  1462 E WindowManager: icon is null!!
10-25 20:14:46.591  1301  1462 E WindowManager: icon is null!!
10-25 20:14:46.620  2225 26662 E HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 103
10-25 20:14:46.634  2225 26662 E HsmCoreServiceImpl: onTransact in code is: 103
10-25 20:14:46.654  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.654  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null calendar
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_FlightStatusMap: getFlightStatusStr flightStatus is error 
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_FlightStatusMap: getFlightStatusStr flightStatus is error 
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null train
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiBoard_11.0.9.305_GsonUtil: JsonSyntaxException|IncompatibleClassChangeError in fromJson classOfT
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.655  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.656  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.657  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.657  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.657  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.657  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.657  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.657  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.657  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_WeatherInfo: parseGsonValue jsonValue is empty 
10-25 20:14:46.657  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_BeanManager: parseBeanValue value is null
10-25 20:14:46.657  5113  5196 E HiSuggestion_11.0.9.305_CardData: buildCardInfo mCardInfoBean is null flight
10-25 20:14:46.729   896   896 E Thermal-daemon:hw_thermal: [pa_0] temp_new :32  temp_old :31
10-25 20:14:46.729   896   896 E Thermal-daemon:hw_thermal: Report temperature: [pa_0] temp :32  report_threshold:1
10-25 20:14:47.334  2326  2326 E HwLauncher: NegativeScreenClientCallBack onServiceStateChanged overlayAttached = true mServiceState = 0
```

Hope someone can help, thx.

Comment: Post the full android logcat output, what you posted probably isn't the important bit.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I updated the log. This is all I got when I run `adb logcat | grep kivy`. It is the first time I checked for the android log. Should I run `adb logcat *:E` or `adb logcat *:F`?

Comment: Don't grep kivy, there's no particular reason that problem lines should contain that string

Comment: Thanks for your help. It fixed by assigning the version of python which 3.7.5 is needed but I am running 3.7.6. It was so close, lol.